# Max regions for status preservation

Tags: ibeacon-android

I wonder why there is a limitation of 50 regions for status preservation?

```
    private static final int MAX_REGIONS_FOR_STATUS_PRESERVATION = 50;
```

And what is the impact of monitoring many regions (like 500) using the `RegionBootstrap` implementation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The library has to serialize and serialize the regions from disk at each app startup.  This is a quick process for a few regions but slows down with more.  At extreme numbers (like 500) the serialization and deserialuzation might take a few seconds and trigger an Application Not Responding (ANR) dialog.  This is why a sanity limit of 50 is in place.

The above limitation aside, monitoring so many regions will burn more CPU and battery because the library has to compare each region with every beacon detected to see if they match.  It is more efficient to design an app to use fewer regions if possible.  If you absolutely must use so many, be sure to test battery drain.

Comment: Ok, I not necessarily need so many in fact. But I need to identify which beacon send the signal and I need to get his major and minor values (in background). As I can not retrieve the major & minor using the bootstrap way (am I right?), the idea was to observe all possible schemes. I also tried to change the region of the bootstrap when I detect a beacon, because I can group some beacons together (and this way I reduce the amount of region to observe). But when device enter doze mode (or sleep >15min?), the job is deferred and I can not catch the second beacon as the user will be out of range.